# Azure Function to be triggered when there is new data inserted in ADX

Tags: azure, azure-functions, eventtrigger, adx

I have a usecase where the data is inserted in ADX via the Event Hub. I want to track the changes in ADX i.e. when ever there is a new data inserted in ADX i want my function to be triggerd.

Also, whenever a new data is inserted in ADX, i want the organization name from the record inserted and pass it to my function. The data inserted from Event Hub to ADX will be in JSON format.

Could anyone help with an optimized approach on how i can achieve this?

I tried using event grid and logic app but i don't think they support direct integration with ADX currently. There is no data export available in ADX or in case of logic apps there is not Azure Data Explorer trigger currently available to track the changes in ADX.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct "ingest" trigger or something like that on ADX. You could, for example, create a second consumer group on the same Event Hub and have an Azure Function listen to that in addition to ADX. Its not a direct link, but if it's good enough for your scenario to assume that ADX will consume the data at the same time as the Function, build your trigger logic in the Function.

Comment: Thank you for the response. We have also thought about this, but the only issue we see here is that there might be failures in loading data to ADX, and still the function would be triggered. We do not want this to happen and only want the function to be triggered once the data is inserted in ADX successfully.

Comment: you could have the Function wait a bit after being triggered (e.g. using a Durable Function timer) and then query ADX if the data actually made it in?

Comment: Would the above solution still be feasible if we have let's say 1000 records being inserted in ADX as part of a single event? Can we query the ADX based on the timestamp would this be an optimized solution in this case?

Comment: I can't really comment on if this is feasible for your specific scenario, as it depends on too many factors. But it might be worth trying it out

Comment: If we go with adding a second consumer group to the same event hub which will be the function. In this case when an event is published to the event hub and that event has 1000 records that are to be inserted in the ADX table since the ADX has a default queueing mechanism for incoming data, we will have a problem with the function since it will be triggered at the same time when the event is published as the function will query the records from ADX using last_timestamp and current_timestamp it might miss out on few records which are yet to be ingested in the ADX due to the queueing mechanism.

Comment: could you please help with the above-mentioned? we do not want to introduce a delay in the function. Can we somehow overwrite this queueing mechanism of ADX and do some kind of bulk insert from an event?

Comment: The answer is depends. What are your volumes ? Have you evaluated using a pipeline in systems like Spark streaming which first inserts data to ADX and uses the same dataframe to publish the same data to EventHub ?

Comment: well, you could always use your Function to ingest data into ADX (instead of from the Event Hub directly). I probably wouldn't do that, but just putting it out there as an option

Comment: Thanks, @silent, could you please provide details on why you would not go with using the function to ingest data into ADX? Is it because the inserting data to ADX issue will be resolved but this involves additional costing to the architecture?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the comment that was mentioned by @silent, we can do this as a Function App.
A combination of timer and ADX bindings is one way to attempt this flow.

To maintain the state of the timer, you may need to use a durable function. A barebone example of this without Durable function is available in the [repo](https://github.com/Azure/Webjobs.Extensions.Kusto/blob/main/samples/samples-csharp/InputBindingSamples/TimerExport/TimeBasedExport.cs)

Disclosure: We maintain this repo. Happy to help further if this fits your case.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ramachandran, can we somehow do it without introducing a delay?I have replied to silent's solution could you please let me know if you have any resolution for the same?

Comment: When you ingest from EH to ADX and you have a certain aggregation policy, there is always a small delay in data ingestion. You can tone it to a lower value, but a no-delay CDC like experience from a journal/bin-log entry is not possible(yet)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the latency you are willing to live with.

One option I can think of is to use the [ingestion_time()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ingestiontimefunction?pivots=azuredataexplorer) special function to discover new data. You can add a scheduled function (with what ever time you want, and once you discover new records (`T | where ingestion_time() > last_check`), you can send them to another function down stream, or just process it there. If you don't want to persist the last_check time, an easy way around that is to have an update_policy to another table with a small retention (say, 5 minutes). Again, it all depends on what latency is good for you.

Another option is using [continues export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/continuous-data-export?source=recommendations#exactly-once-export), which would garauntee extactly once, and adding an event subscription to the target storage, and wire that to your function. This is much easier to manager, but can in theory miss the `intervalBetweenRuns`, so it will be less predictable.

Comment: Thanks for your response Daniel, i have replied to silent's solution could you please let me know if you have any resolution for the same?